# How can I check if a leftJoin is set in?

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4, left-join

I have a form filter with few custom search fields.

In the `addXXXQuery` functions, I have to use join on a table which is the same for some fields.

Can I check if innerJoin for that particular table is already set in another `addXXXQuery`?

[EDIT] example:

```
public function addIsPaidColumnQuery(Doctrine_Query $query, $field, $values)
{
  if ($values) {
    $rootAlias = $query->getRootAlias();
    $query->leftJoin($rootAlias.".Inscription i");
          ->andWhere("i.is_paid = ?", $values);
  }
}

public function addActTypeColumnQuery(Doctrine_Query $query, $field, $values)
{
  if ($values) {
    $rootAlias = $query->getRootAlias();
    $query->leftJoin($rootAlias.".Inscription i")
          ->leftJoin("i.Act a")

    $query->addWhere("a.act_type_id = ?", $values);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we see an example? I don't get the point ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can retrieve the `$params` from the query, and check if the join is already there, something like this:

```
public function addIsPaidColumnQuery(Doctrine_Query $query, $field, $values)
{
  if ($values)
  {
    $rootAlias = $query->getRootAlias();
    $leftjoin  = $rootAlias.".Inscription i";
    $params    = $query->getParams();

    if (!isset($params['join']) || (isset($params['join']) && !in_array($leftjoin, $params)))
    {
      $query->leftJoin($leftjoin);
    }

    $query->andWhere("i.is_paid = ?", $values);
  }
}
```

You can see in the code, [how a leftJoin in added](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine1/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Query/Abstract.php#L1673).

Comment: That is one is not correct for this situation I'm afraid. The `getParams()` method for the query returns the paramaters values used to fill any placeholders in the query (`?` or named ones). So you will never have the contents of `$leftjoin` inside the `$params['join']`. What worked for me was this: `$query->contains($leftjoin)` which checks if the given DQL is used within the query.

Comment: `getParams` also returns join, since [all joins are stored inside](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine1/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Query/Abstract.php#L1645-L1679). `contains` [should also work](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine1/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Query.php#L413-L425), even if I find this solution a bit dirty since it searchs inside the **whole** DQL.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a method, that would tell me if a join for a table is set. However the more I thought about the existence of such method, the less sence it made for it. So to check if I already used a join in the filter query I set a class variable `$leftJoinInscriptionSet`.

```
private $leftJoinInscriptionSet = false;

...

public function addIsPaidColumnQuery(Doctrine_Query $query, $field, $values)
{
  if ($values) {
    $this->setLeftJoinInscription($query);

    $query->andWhere("i.is_paid = ?", $values);
  }
}

...


private function setLeftJoinInscription(Doctrine_Query $query) {
  if (!$this->leftJoinInscriptionSet) {
      $rootAlias = $query->getRootAlias();
      $query->leftJoin($rootAlias.".Inscription i");
      $this->leftJoinInscriptionSet = true;
  }
}
```